# Case Milestone related list

Tags: casemilestone

How can i see value in case milestones related list.
[image]

Comment: Have you checked this doc: [Using the Case Milestones Related List](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=cases_milestones.htm&language=en_US)

Comment: Yes, But I am not able to getting it.
I need step by step process.

Answer (score 1):

The doc [Using the Case Milestones Related List](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=cases_milestones.htm&language=en_US) says that

> The Case Milestones related list on a case detail page displays a list
>   of milestones that **automatically apply to the case** due to an
>   **entitlement process**.

So visit this link [To create milestone and entitlement process](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=entitlements_setting_milestones.htm&language=en) first.

[image: Setting and using the Entitlement Process]

[Documentation](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=entitlements_milestones_overview.htm&language=en)

Comment: I have done this step and case milestone related list also appear on case record as i have posted it . But now i want to make connection between both of it .i.e. i can see milestones record on case milestones related list

Comment: I guess you have to check or provide information about your entitlement process for more information

Comment: wait, let me try it

Answer (score 1):

The Case Milestones related list on a case detail page displays a list of milestones that automatically apply to the case due to an entitlement process. Milestones are required steps in your support process. They're metrics that represent service levels to provide to each of your customers. Examples of milestones include First Response and Resolution Times on cases.

- No records to display appears in the related list if no milestones apply to the case.
- The related list contains fields that your company has chosen to display, based on its business processes. Depending on your company's requirements, you may see some or all of the following fields.

To create milestone and entitlement process first.

[Please see this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6NoWAJ_vZgE)

Comment: Means that We need not to do anything,  displaying the record of milestone on case milestone relatedlist. it will come out automatically on milestone relatedlist.

Answer (score 0):

Did you add 'Entitlement Name' field on case page layout? Also change 'Entitlement Name' as Visible/Readonly on Case Object from Field Accessibility setting.

Create a case by selecting an 'Entitlement Name', then you will be able to see case Milestone records as per the entry and exit criteria's.

Answer (score 0):

You have not created any milestones and added them to the entitlement process. once you add milestones set the entry criteria for them and the milestone kicks in you should be able to see them.